# Append current message to the previous message

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I want to display in the messageBox as following:

> Initializing
>
> Collecting Log Data...Collected  (i.e two separate strings in the same line)

But the output in the messageBox is:

> Initializing
>
> Collecting Log Data...
>
> Collected

How can I display the last two strings in the same line in a ListBox.  Thanks for your help.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="messageBox" ........ />
</Grid>
```

And the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showMessage("Initializing");
        showMessage("Collecting Log Data...");
        //do some time consuming processing
        showMessage("Collected");
    }

    public void showMessage(string message)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem()
        item.Content = msg;
        messageBox.Items.Add(item);

    }
}
```

Comment: unclear, please elaborate more

Comment: `ListBox` is a very strange choice for your task.

Comment: i am just wondering why you use ListBox for showing message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void showMessage(string message, bool InLine)
{
    if (InLine)
        messageBox.Items[messageBox.Items.Count-1] += message;
    else
        messageBox.Items.Add(message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks lomed. Your help solved my issue.  Just one more question, how do I change the foreground color of the appended line in the messageBox.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Create a method that append your message to the last added item to the listbox.

Something like this:

```
public void appendMessage(string message)
{
    ListBoxItem item = messageBox.Items[messageBox.Items.Count-1];
    item.Content += message;
}
```